Rayleigh iterate function in Python
I should write a Rayleigh quotient iteration function x, k = rayleigh iterate(A,x0, eig),
which takes a matrix A, an initial vector x0, and an approximate eigenvalue eig as arguments and returns an eigenvector x together with the number k of iterations used. I have implemented a rayleigh qt(A,x), which takes a matrix A and approximate eigenvector x, and returns the approximate eigenvalue $\lambda$. But how do I rewrite my code eigenvalue and give out the eigenvector? I think I must use some inverse function and use LUfactorization. Do anyone have some inspiriting code or can explain mathematically how to do it?

You're saying "I did a thing I'm not going to show you, how do I make it work using ". I think you need to be more specific if you want others to help you.

This looks like an assignment question. You must atleast make an effort to solve it yourself and then ask if you have any specific doubts. It is not ok to ask us to solve your assignment.
